# C# - Excel 2013 how to change chart style

Tags: c#, excel, automation, office-interop

I'm trying to chnage style for a chart in excel 2013 but it only changes color:

```
Range chartRange;
ChartObjects wsCharts = (ChartObjects)workSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)wsCharts.Add(0, 0, 900, 500);
Chart workChart = myChart.Chart;

chartRange = workSheet.get_Range("A1", "D12");
workChart.SetSourceData(chartRange, Type.Missing);
workChart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
```

now the chart looks like this:
[image: original]

and then `workChart.ChartStyle = 8;` changes the bar's color to:
[image: new]

instead of the chart's style to:
[image]

I also tried playing with the `ChartWizard` method and other properties of `Chart` but with no luck so far.

Comment: Have you tried recording a Macro doing what you want to do in Excel?

Comment: I can't use Macros for security reasons.

Comment: Can't you record a Macro then take a look at the VBA and use it to write your interop code?

Comment: This'll work, but unfortunately I can't use Macros. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
workChart.ChartStyle = 209;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Can you explain how did you come up with this number?

Comment: I used the method that JMK described:
1. start recording a macro
2. change the style
3. stop recording and view the macro