# How to set Excel chart style in vb

Tags: excel, vb.net, charts

I am exporting an excel chart throught vb.net but I want to change his style. The problem is I'm currently only been able to change his colors.

**See the code below:**

```
Private Sub ExportExcel()
    Dim PerfilSonho As Boolean = False

    If PerfilSonhoAtivo(CB_FuncaoNivel.SelectedItem, CB_CompetenciaNivel.SelectedItem) = True Then 'Ativar barras de Perfil Sonho
        PerfilSonho = True
    End If

    Dim excel As New Excel.Application 'Create Excel Application instance
    excel.Visible = True 'Set Excel Application to visible
    excel.Workbooks.Add() 'Add a new excel workbook

    'Add 3 Columns header for data fields
    excel.Range("A1").Value2 = "Operários"
    excel.Range("B1").Value2 = CT_Niveis.Series(0).LegendText
    If PerfilSonho = True Then
        excel.Range("C1").Value2 = CT_Niveis.Series(1).LegendText
    End If

    'Add data to the Cells
    Dim i As Integer = 2
    For j As Integer = 0 To CT_Niveis.Series(0).Points.Count - 1
        excel.Range("A" & i).Value2 = XChart(j)
        excel.Range("B" & i).Value2 = CT_Niveis.Series(0).Points(j).YValues
        i += 1
    Next
    If PerfilSonho = True Then
        i = 2
        For x As Integer = 0 To CT_Niveis.Series(1).Points.Count - 1
            excel.Range("C" & i).Value2 = CT_Niveis.Series(1).Points(x).YValues
            i += 1
        Next
    End If

    Dim range As Excel.Range = excel.Range("A1") 'Add range
    Dim chart As Excel.Chart = excel.ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add(After:=excel.ActiveSheet) 'Add Chart
    chart.ChartWizard(Source:=range.CurrentRegion, Title:=CT_Niveis.Titles(0).Text) 'Add chart data source & title

    'Set Chart Style
    chart.ChartStyle = 27
    chart.Axes(2, 1).maximumscale = 4.5
    chart.Axes(2, 1).minimumscale = 0
End Sub
```

**The Excel is exported like this:**
[image]

**But I wanted to change it to look like this, for example:**
[image]

Is it even possible? Or we can only change his colors?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504337/c-sharp-excel-2013-how-to-change-chart-style

Comment: @Mkn Thank you so much! It worked. I was losing my mind over this. Really, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mkn commented in this comment section, the following link answered my question: [C# - Excel 2013 how to change chart style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504337/c-sharp-excel-2013-how-to-change-chart-style)

Basically, all I had to do was change the **chart style** from 27 to 209 like this -

```
chart.ChartStyle = 209
```

Now the chart looks exactly like I wanted -
[image: Chart Style]